# Batch convert to UTF8 using Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I'm encountering a little problem with my file encodings.
Sadly, as of yet I still am not on good terms with everything where encoding matters; although I have learned plenty since I began using Ruby 1.9.

My problem at hand: I have several files to be processed, which are expected to be in UTF-8 format. But I do not know how to batch convert those files properly; e.g. when in Ruby, I open the file, encode the string to utf8 and save it in another place.
Unfortunately that's not how it is done - the file is still in ANSI.
At least that's what my Notepad++ says.
I find it odd though, because the string was clearly encoded to UTF-8, and I even set the **File.open** parameter `:encoding` to `'UTF-8'`. My shell is set to CP65001, which I believe also corresponds to UTF-8.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks!

/e: What's more, when in Notepad++, I can convert manually as such:

- Selecting everything,
- copy,
- setting encoding to UTF-8 (here, \x-escape-sequences can be seen)
- pasting everything from clipboard

Done! Escape-characters vanish, file can be processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately that's not how it is done - the file is still in ANSI. At least that's what my Notepad++ says.

UTF-8 was designed to be a superset of ASCII, which means that most of the printable ASCII characters are the same in UTF-8. For this reason it's not possible to distinguish between ASCII and UTF-8 unless you have "special" characters. These special characters are represented using multiple bytes in UTF-8.

It's well possible that your conversion is actually working, but you can double-check by trying your program with special characters.

Also, one of the best utilities for converting between encodings is [`iconv`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv), which also [has ruby bindings](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/classes/Iconv.html).

Comment: I do have special characters, for instance *ü* or *ß*. I will look into *iconv*, it was also mentioned in the excellent articles about ruby encoding by [James Edward Gray II](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings)

Comment: Still, Notepad++ is probably not able to detect the encoding. So if it messes up those characters when viewing in ANSI/ASCII-mode, your conversion is working.